# How to add relative movement to multiple virtual cameras?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am using a Cinemachine state driver to transition between my 8 directional cameras orbiting my player. Right now my player script is set to a basic isometric character controller:

**Player.cs**

```cs
    public float speed = 5f;
    Vector3 forward;
    Vector3 right;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        forward.y = 0;
        forward = Vector3.Normalize(forward);
        right = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 90, 0)) * forward;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKey)
        {
            Move();
        }

    }

    void Move ()
    {
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        Vector3 rightMovement = right * speed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector3 upMovement = forward * speed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 heading = Vector3.Normalize(rightMovement + upMovement);
        transform.forward += heading;
        transform.position += rightMovement;
        transform.position += upMovement;
    }
```

[image]
I want the players move direction to reflect the direction of the camera. For example, using W (from WASD) will always move the player up. Could I edit the script to pick up the direction of each of my virtual cameras and add that to my player controller or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to change the movement of the keys according to the angle of the camera. This is done as follows with `transform.TransformDirection`. When the movement is synchronized with the direction of the camera, it causes the <kbd>W</kbd> key to press the character towards the ground, because the angle in front of the camera is inside the ground. To solve the problem, we set y to zero and then normalize the axis.

```cs
public float speed = 10f;
void Update()
{
    var moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f , Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    moveInput = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(moveInput);
    moveInput.y = 0;
    moveInput = moveInput.normalized;
    
    transform.position += moveInput * Time.deltaTime * speed;
}
```

Comment: This worked but the players response is lagging, it takes a second to respond to start and stop movement. I tried changing it to a fixedupdate but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Of course, this code returns you the modified `moveInput`, and you can use the directions for the desired move with rigidbody or something else. Transform.position is an example. To solve the lag problem and smooth the movement, you must use `lerp` methods, If you are familiar with this process, the problem of movement will be solved, otherwise which require more research or another question.

Comment: Ive been looking into lerp methods and I understand (i think) how they work but i'm getting stuck on how to implement this to my existing code. I understand that for a Vector3.Lerp i need a start position and desired position along with a fraction for time, i don't know how to set those when the movement relies on the camera position. I tried making the transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.postion, moveInput, lerpFacter) and set the lerpfactor to Range(0, 1); but that didnt work. I also tried adding a lerp function to all different parts of the code and haven't gotten anywhere.